# How can I reset counter to 0 if value from function parameter is different in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am sending value dynamically in counter function i.e, button can be counter(0), counter(1),counter(2), etc.

Now say if count = 0 (i.e, counter(0)), then I want to increment global variable i.

And now count = 1, then reset the global variable i to 0 and again start incrementing from first.

Again, say if button counter is 0 again and for counter 0 last increment was 4, then it must start from 5.

How can I do that in javascript. Is it possible to do so?

```js
var i =0;
function counter(count){
i++;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick=counter(0)>Change counter</button>
```

```html
var count = 0;
function myfunction() {
         <button type="button" onclick="counter(` + count + `)" class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 float-right">Change Counter</button>
         count++;
                }
```

Comment: I read this several times and do not get it. You have ONE button and the button sends 0 each time it is clicked. If I click that button once, then i is 1. How will this ever reach 5? OR do you have 5 buttons? If so, have 5 buttons in the snippet above

Comment: I have other function that increment button counter from 0 to 1, 2,3,4,5

Comment: So make us a [mcve]

Comment: ok I will add other function to here.

Comment: Your counter function actually does nothing, you pass a number to a function you are not using and it returns nothing

Comment: I am appending button with another function which change button counter to 0, 1, 2 ,3 4, 5.

Comment: Are you using frameworks or something? You cant use html in plain javascript like that

Comment: I am using jquery

Comment: you have a variable "count" that is never used. if you want different behavior based on count, you need to have some if statements in your logic.

Comment: the code you added in a NEW snippet will never run. It is not valid JavaScript. Please make a ***[mcve]***

Comment: @mplungjan, There is another button with onclick event calling myFunction() which then append new button with onclick event calling counter where counter initially is 0 and it increments to 1,2,3,etc

Comment: Not sure what your plan is, I assume this is incorrect since your question is still unclear. So here's is something: https://jsfiddle.net/f9jdy1os/

Answer (score 2):

You need a separate counter for each number. You can't do this with a single global. Otherwise it resets when you change the button you click and you can never get the old value back when you go back to the previous button.

Use an object to store the counters in.

If you need to have a global value with the latest value of the most recently manipulated counter, copy the value to it afterwards.

```js
let lastCounterValue = 0;
const counters = {};

const increment = event => {
  const button = event.currentTarget;
  const counterId = button.textContent;
  if (!(counterId in counters)) {
    counters[counterId] = 0;
  }
  counters[counterId]++;
  lastCounterValue = counters[counterId];
  console.log({
    lastCounterValue,
    counters
  });
}

document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", increment));
```

```html
<button>0</button>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

Comment: i will try this Quentin

Answer (score 1):

I would keep an array for each button with an unique identifier.

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="counter('a', 0)">Change counter</button>
<button type="button" onclick="counter('b', 3)"">Change counter</button>
```

JS

```
var clickArr = {};
function counter(id, count){
   clickArr[id] = !isNaN(clickArr[id]) ? (clickArr[id]+1) : count;
   console.log(clickArr);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var i = 0;

function cal() {
  let cache = 0;
  return function(count) {
    if (count == 0) {
      if (i == 0) {
        i = ++cache;
        // use memoized val
      } else {
        i++;
        cache = i;
        // increment
      }
    } else if (count == 1) {
      /*set to 0, don't update cache now, 
      wait for next input */
      i = 0;
    } else {
      i = count;
      cache = count;
    }
  }
}

var counter = cal();
counter(0)
counter(0)
counter(0)
console.log('3', i)
counter(99)
console.log('99', i)
counter(1)
counter(0)
console.log('100', i)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.